# Graph flattened on the y's axe

Tags: graph, axes

I am trying to draw a hypotrochoïde figure, but my graph is flattened on the axes of y. I cann'ot find the error. Please help me! Thank you in advance! :) 
    #Définir la fonction hypotrochoïde
    def hypo(R,r,d,phi0=0,color='k'):
        """
        Cette fonction calcule la position du crayon en fonction de phi. 
        Par défaut, la valeur de "phi0" est égale à zéro et la valeur de "c" \
        est égale à la couleur noire, soit 'color=k'. 
        """

```
if R<1000 and r<1000 and d<1000 :
    x=(R-r)*np.cos(thêta)+d*(np.cos(-((R-r)/r)*thêta+phi0))
    y=(R-r)*np.sin(thêta)+d*(np.sin(-((R-r)/r)*thêta+phi0))


else: 
    print('Erreur! Les valeurs de R, r et d sont restreint à des \
          nombres entiers entre 0 et 1000. ')
return x,y

#L'utilisateur entre les valeurs de R, r et d
valeurR=input("SVP entrez la valeur de R :")
vR=float(valeurR)
R=int(vR)

valeurr=input("SVP entrez la valeur de r :")
vr=float(valeurr)
r=int(vr)

valeurd=input("SVP entrez la valeur de d :")
vd=float(valeurd)
d=int(vd)

#Calculer la valeur de n (entier positif)
m=r
n=(r/(R-r))*m

#Calculer le nombres de tours 
thêta=np.linspace(0,2*n*np.pi,100)


#Affichage du graphique
plt.plot(hypo(R, r, d))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title("Hypotrochoïdes")
plt.xlabel('x') 
plt.ylabel('y') 
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```